# Calculating with y-axis labels of stacked bar plot (either *4 or into percent)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I know this is a topic already often addressed, nevertheless I did not find a satisfying solution to this query:

I would like to plot a stacked bar chart in 100%. The stacks should include the absolute count, the y-axis should illustrate the percentage. Besides it containes 1 grouping and 3 facets: [image]

As you can see, each group contains 25 participants (y-axis). I am looking for an easy  solution to change the y-axis labels into percentages; e.g. y-axis-breaks times four (25*4 = 100). Alternatively I tried to create a second dataframe for ratios, but had troubles including them in this plot.

```
event_labels <- c("T0\nBaseline", "T1\nDay 7", "T2\nWeek 6", "T3\nWeek 12", "T4\n6 Months\nFollow-Up")
names(event_labels) <- c("t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4")

rem_eular_response <- rem_eular_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=gruppe,
             fill=factor(number_ordered))) +
  geom_bar() +
  stat_count(geom = "text",
             aes(label = (..count..)),
             position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
             size = 4) +
  facet_wrap(~event,
            scales="free",
            ncol=3,
            labeller = labeller(event = event_labels)) +
  labs(title ="",
       fill="") +
  ylab("Patients achieving response [%]") + 
  xlab("") + 
  #labs(color="", linetype="")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill="lightgrey", 
                                      color="transparent"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color="black",
                                 size=0.2),
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title=element_text())+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('DGE', 'Fasting'))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Accent',
                    na.value = "grey70",
                    labels=c('Good Responder', 'Moderate Responder', 'Non-Responder',
                             'Missing'))
```

Here a minimal reproducible example of my data:

```
structure(list(sid = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8), gruppe = c("DGE", "DGE", "DGE", "DGE", 
"DGE", "DGE", "DGE", "DGE", "DGE", "Fasten", "Fasten", "Fasten", 
"Fasten", "Fasten", "Fasten", "Fasten", "Fasten", "Fasten", "DGE", 
"DGE"), responsetype = c("das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", 
"das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", 
"das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", 
"das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", 
"das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", 
"das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", 
"das28esr_response", "das28esr_response", "das28esr_response"
), event = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", 
"t3", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", 
"t2"), number = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA), responsetype_ordered = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("remission", "das28esr_response"), class = "factor"), 
    number_ordered = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA), .Label = c("2", 
    "1", "0"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Do you have an idea for a quick and simple solution?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide  `event_labels`

Comment: Does `position = "fill"` fit the bill?

Comment: @TarJae thanks for the remark, I included it in the code above:
event_labels <- c("T0\nBaseline", "T1\nDay 7", "T2\nWeek 6", "T3\nWeek 12", "T4\n6 Months\nFollow-Up")
names(event_labels) <- c("t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4")

Comment: @teunbrand thank you for your comment, unfortunately position ="stack" / "fill" only refers to the text item (counts) in the bars

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant to put it in `geom_bar(position = "fill")` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to your code:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0((x/max(x))*100, "%"))
```

For the given example dataset without(`event_labels`):
[image]

Comment: This looks great and works perfectly, thank you for the quick and easy fix!